# Stored procedure inside a insert statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to generate random data for my sql server database. Ive created a stored procedure that takes length of string to be generated but the problem is that it wont allow me to call it inside the insert statement.

```
insert into table1 (varchar_data,int_data) value ((sp_GenerateRandomString 4),CAST(RAND() * 10 AS INT) % 6 + 1 )
```

also this is not working

```
insert into table1  (varchar_data,int_data) select ((sp_GenerateRandomString 4),CAST(RAND() * 10 AS INT) % 6 + 1 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a **user defined function** instead of a stored procedure. A stored procedure cannot be used in expressions, but functions can.

A good introduction can be found here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions

Comment: @bjan Why would that be an issue in this case?

Comment: it is not related with this question though, but what if your sp is executing an update statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ... EXEC sp_procedure
```

Comment: It is not working on sql server 2000, can you please explain it more

Comment: This is a poor answer @Remus. You need to explain the problem that the  asker is having, and how you solution fixes that problem.